# Multi value variable in Python3.4

Tags: python-3.x

I have a variable which can have multiple values. A value can be:

- a range with name (e.g. (`"well-known ports" range(1,1024))`)
- a single value (e.g. `345`)
- a tuple with name (e.g. `("Ip Versions", (4,6)`)

Basically only numbers and strings are used. 
How should I implement such a variable (or class) if the following operations should be able to make:

- add/del a value (if it is not already present)
- check if values1 is part of values2. If yes get the corresponding string (e.g. "well-known")
- generate intersection of values1 and values2
- generate the union of values1 and values2

I known that with a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) I can do most of that stuff, but I can not check if a value is in the range:

```
values1 = set(1,2, ("Port list1", range(3,100)))
2 in values1
[True]
30 in values1
[false]
```

Comment: What about a dictionary?

Comment: What are you trying to use this for? Maybe there's a better way :)